# References mentioning the relationship between cumulants of uniform distribution and the Bernoulli numbers?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, bernoulli-numbers

Is there anyone knows where is some official reference mentioning the relationship between cumulants of uniform distribution and the Bernoulli numbers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant#Cumulants_of_some_continuous_probability_distributions)?

Comment: I saw this post: 
http://sci4um.com/about6424-Bernoulli-numbers-and-cumulants-of-uniform-distributions.html
but do not have the book from Gian-Carlo Rota.
@MichaelHardy: Could you please confirm if this book is a good reference?

Comment: The book barely mentions this fact in passing and is not very clear. The book is (almost?) entirely a collection of reprints.  The book takes its name from the second reprint, "Finite Operator Calculus", which appeared originally in the _Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications_, v. 42, no. 3, June 1973. Section 14 of that paper has a long list of problems for further research. The 5th item in that list says, near the end of that item: Bernoulli numbers "are, apart from a factor, the cumulants of the uniform distribution". "Apart from a factor" is not all that clear, considering....

Comment: ....that the factor by which the $n$th Bernoulli number gets multiplied is $1/n$.

Comment: I assume by "official" you mean "refereed" or something like that.  I don't know of one off hand, but I seem to recall I went through the derivation once.  I'll see if I can figure out the details.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks for your comments. Have you found any further detail there? If so, please let me know.